# Side limit of a definite integral

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

How do I calculate this?

$$\lim_{x\to \:0,\:x>0}\frac{1}{x}\int _{2x}^{7x^2}\:f\left(t\right)dt$$
Where
$$\:f:\left(0,\infty \right)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
$$\:\:f\left(x\right)=\frac{\ln\left(1+x\right)}{x}\:$$

I tried calculating the integral but to no avail. I tried computing it with online integral calculators but they give me the answer with polylogarithm which I haven't studied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function
$$
F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)dt.
$$
Note also that $F(0) = 0$. Then you are looking at the limit
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{F(7x^2) - F(2x)}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{F(7x^2) - F(0)}{x - 0} - \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{F(2x) - F(0)}{x - 0}
$$
which is a difference of two derivatives (where one must use the chain rule). In particular,
$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{F(7x^2) - F(0)}{x} = (F \circ g)'(0)$$
where $g = 7x^2$. Since $F'(x) = f(x)$, see that
$$(F\circ g)'(x) = f(g(x))g'(x) = \frac{\ln(1 + 7x^2)}{7x^2}14x = \frac{2\ln(1 + 7x^2)}{x} \to 0.$$
You can do similarly with the other derivative (except note that the resulting limit isn't $0$).